# LWC: NavigationMixin.Navigate not able to refresh/reload the whole page

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a Community page called page_A and a LWC is on this page. The HTML file has these two parts where {flag} is a tracked variable in js file.

```
<template if:true={flag}>     
... A part ...                                                                                                 
</template>                               

<template if:false={flag}>   
... B part ...                         
</template>
```

In the js file there is a @wire Apex method called "getFlag" that returns {flag} value.

```
@wire (getFlag)
wiredGetFlag({error,data}){
    if (data) {
        this.flag = data.flag;
    } else if (error) {

    }
}
```

Suppose flag is true now and "A part" is shown. After doing something in another component in another page, I want to navigate back to "A_page" to see that flag is now turned to "false" and "B part" is shown.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'standard__namedPage',
    attributes: {
     pageName: 'page_A',
    },
});
```

It turns out that after navigating back to page_A, the value would not be updated. Only if I press F5 to reload the page would the @wired function be run again so that I can see flag value turned "false".

Any idea how I can reload the page in SFDC community using NavigationMixin.Navigate without pressing F5 by hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your Apex method use Cachable? You can call this method imperatively in connected callback and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

### Using refreshApex()

Since you are using a wired function, you can invoke `refreshApex()` to refresh the component's data when the component is loaded (i.e. in `connectedCallback()`), rather than pulling data from the cache.

Using the code that you provided, the module with the wired function would become:

```
// IMPORTANT - remember to import the function
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

...

@track flag = {};

// Introduce property to track the wired result to refresh later
wiredFlag;

@wire (getFlag)
wiredGetFlag(result){
    this.wiredFlag = result;

    // Destructure result into two variables: data and error
    const { data, error } = result;

    if (data) {
        this.flag = data.flag;
    } else if (error) {

    }
}

connectedCallback() {
    // Refresh the data on load
    if (this.wiredFlag && this.wiredFlag.data) {
        refreshApex(this.wiredFlag);
    }
}
```

**Note:** you cannot refresh data that has been fetched imperatively using `refreshApex()` since it was never cached, as per documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

---

If you do not need to handle the wired function error in JS, you can simplify the module:

**JS**

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

...

@wire (getflag) flag;

connectedCallback() {
    if (this.flag && this.flag.data) {
        refreshApex(this.flag);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <template if:true={flag.data}>{flag.data.flag}</template>
    <template if:true={flag.error}>{flag.error}</template>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi @akiradev, 

thank you so much for your answer. I gave it a try but it was in vain. 

I think what is needed is that I need to be able to run "/@wire (getFlag) wiredGetFlag" again without refreshing the page. 

I finally did it by using hyperlink "<a href" from another page so that it will surely refresh the page and run "/@wire (getFlag) wiredGetFlag" on loading. It is just a workaround and might not be the best way though.

Comment: Is there any proper solution found for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval JavaScript function to refresh the page from the component . copy and paste the below code after the line from where you wanted to refresh the page.

eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");